# I need to write a program that prompts the user for two numbers and then it prints some outputs

Tags: java

The issue that I am having is that I do not know how to implement the additional classes into my main class. The question has the user picking two numbers from a scanner, then the program lists the sum, difference, product, average, distance, maximum, and minimum of the two numbers. I know how to get the sum, difference etc... but how do I tell the main class the print them. **A second class is required, although it can be done in the main.**
Here is my code so far,
Main class:

```
package p4_4_class_pair;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4_4_Class_Pair {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input 1st number: ");
        in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Input 2nd number: ");
        in.nextDouble(); 
        System.out.println();
        
    }
    
}
```

Additional Class:

```
package p4_4_class_pair;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pair {
   
    private double sum;
    private double difference;
    private double product;
    private double average;
    private double distance;
    private double max;
    private double min;
    
    /**
     * Constructs a pair
     * @param aFirst the first value of the pair
     * @param aSecond the second value of the pair
     */
    public Pair(double aFirst, double aSecond) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        aFirst = in.nextDouble();
        aSecond = in.nextDouble(); 
        
    }
    
    
    public double addSum(double a, double b){
        sum = a + b; 
        return sum; 
    }
    
    /**
     * Computes the sum of the values of this pair
     * @return the sum of the first and second values
     */
    public double getSum(){
        return sum; 
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused about your implementation. You are reading the values in the main method and again inside the constructor of the Pair class.

One possible implementation could be like this one for the class with the main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4_4_Class_Pair {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input 1st number: ");
        double firstNum = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Input 2nd number: ");
        double secondNum = in.nextDouble();

        Pair pair = new Pair(firstNum,secondNum);

        System.out.println("Sum = " + pair.sum());
        System.out.println("Difference = " + pair.difference());
        System.out.println("Product = " + pair.product());


    }

}
```

And class Pair :

```
public class Pair {

    private double sum;
    private double difference;
    private double product;
    private double average;
    private double distance;
    private double max;
    private double min;
    private double firstNum;
    private double secondNum;

    /**
     * Constructs a pair
     * @param aFirst the first value of the pair
     * @param aSecond the second value of the pair
     */
    public Pair(double aFirst, double aSecond) {
        firstNum = aFirst;
        secondNum = aSecond;
    }


    public double sum(){
        sum = firstNum + secondNum;
        return sum;
    }

    public double difference() {
        difference = firstNum - secondNum;
        return difference;
        }

    public double product(){
        product = firstNum * secondNum;
        return product;
        }

}
```

You can implement the remaining methods using the same way.
Also, please note that there are various ways to achieve your desired task, so let me know if you are looking for a specific way to do this.

Comment: Yes, your code makes sense, and thank you for guiding me in the right direction. There is also one requirement for this program, it must utilize this statement public double getSum() in the Pair class.

Comment: What do you mean by utilizing getSum()?

If you mean you want to pass the values for the method, then you can do this: 

`public double getSum(double n1, double n2){
return n1 + n2;
}`

then in the main method you can call and pass the values:

getSum(5,6);

Sorry if this is not what you want.

Comment: If you change the name of the method in Pair class, then you must change it also in the main method. In the part where you call it. pair.getSum();

Answer (score 0):

```
Pair pair =  new Pair(first, second)
```

in your main method, the print pair.addSum

Comment: It's giving me an error for the provided code, I switched "first and second" to aFirst and aSecond as I have in my code. It says that it cannot find the symbol, aFirst and aSecond.